# iOS localization, language change in app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localization

//
Hey, i got a problem with localization.
working on app with 2 languages, you can change language in app on login screen with simple button, and it all works when i made it in storyboard, but localalized strings dont and i can not find solution.
//
this is how you change languages and it work with storyboard elements
//

```
fileprivate extension LoginViewController {

    @IBAction func changeLanguage(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == currentBtn { return }
        currentBtn?.backgroundColor = nil
        switch sender {
        case gbBtn:
            Locale.updateLanguage(code: "en")
        case rsBtn:
            Locale.updateLanguage(code: "sr")
            default:
            break
        }
        currentBtn = sender
        currentBtn?.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

// this is not working

```
@IBAction func alertAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("pera", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("toma", comment: ""), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "stisni", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I made strings files where i put this keys but nothing happen, compiler show me the keys when i run.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to overwrite the apple languges.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Then you have to reload each label text.